# is there a way to make the transparency in the google map marker not clickable

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps, svg, google-maps-markers

ok so i have a google map app i read in svgs from my html, and then make markers out of them.  But now the problem is that the transparency that comes with the marker is clickable aswell, now this creates a problem in close clusters. So my question is, is it possible to make only the bit of the marker that has a path clickable instead of the whole area, aside from using "path:" instead of "url:" in google map markers.

So currently:

```
//gets it from my html and treats it like a path
 var iconUrl = "data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8," + escape(document.getElementById("builtMarker").innerHTML);
 var sizeX = 160;
 var sizeY = 140;
 //make my custom icon
 var icon = {
     url: iconUrl,
     scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(sizeX, sizeY),
     anchor: new google.maps.Point(sizeX / 2, sizeY / 2)
 };

loc = new google.maps.LatLng(63.68212926717004, -99.33484864981511);
marker = new google.maps.Marker({
     position: loc,
     map: map,
     draggable: false,
     icon: icon,
     zIndex: -20,
 });
```

https://jsfiddle.net/y8yj86og/3/

So if you look at that fiddle the "hover" hand changes before it actually gets to the icon, my svg markers are quite complex and change on size depending on parameters, so changing the viewbox size will cause it to be cut off when i make a bigger icon. Is there any other way to go about this?  Like a way to set the viewbox size to auto or something

Comment: The marker will at the end lies within a div, so it's automatically a square. So there is no way to do what you want in this case. The only way to do it properly is build the SVG by yourself and then append it to the map.

Comment: There is an option `shape` in the [`google.maps.MarkerOptions`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#MarkerOptions) object which is of type [`MarkerShape`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#MarkerShape) and will accept a circle, a rectangle or a polygon restricting the target for mouse events to this region.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a `shape` option for a [`google.maps.Marker`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/3.exp/reference#MarkerShape) that allows you to specify the "clickable" region for the marker for non-IE browsers.

> **MarkerShape object specification**

> google.maps.MarkerShape object specification

> This object **defines the clickable region of a marker image for browsers other than Internet Explorer**. The shape consists of two properties — type and coord — which define the non-transparent region of an image. A MarkerShape object is not required on Internet Explorer since the browser does not fire events on the transparent region of an image by default.

For your icon (at least the one you provided in your example) that shape is approximately a triangle:

```
marker = new google.maps.Marker({
  position: loc,
  map: map,
  draggable: false,
  icon: icon,
  zIndex: -20,
  shape: { 
      type: 'poly',
      coords: [50,50,  105,50,  75,90,  50,50]
  } 
});
```

[updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/y8yj86og/4/)

**code snippet:**

```js
var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(38.392303, -86.931067);

map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"), {
  zoom: 4,
  center: myLatlng,
  mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
});

var iconUrl = "data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8," + escape(document.getElementById("builtMarker").innerHTML);
var sizeX = 160;
var sizeY = 140;
var icon = {
  url: iconUrl,
  scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(sizeX, sizeY),
  anchor: new google.maps.Point(sizeX / 2, sizeY / 2)
};
loc = new google.maps.LatLng(63.68212926717004, -99.33484864981511);
marker = new google.maps.Marker({
  title: "SVG mark",
  position: loc,
  map: map,
  draggable: false,
  icon: icon,
  zIndex: -20,
  shape: {
    type: 'poly',
    coords: [50, 50, 105, 50, 75, 90, 50, 50]
  }
});
map.panTo(loc);
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk"></script>
<div id="map-canvas" style="height:600px"></div>
<div id="builtMarker">
  <svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" width="595.28px" height="841.89px" viewBox="0 0 595.28 841.89" enable-background="new 0 0 595.28 841.89" xml:space="preserve">
    <path fill="#74C380" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="M319.669,455.002c-11.99-16.691-22.492-15.168-22.492-15.168v0.016
    c-0.006,0-10.504-1.488-22.475,15.23c1.299,3.563,22.51,61.154,22.51,61.154l0.004-0.02
    C297.216,516.213,318.372,458.568,319.669,455.002z" />
    <path opacity="0.54" fill="#74C380" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="M297.187,440.656" />
    <path fill="#234821" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="M297.171,422.465c0,0-13.275-0.682-26.111,12.199
    c0.713,1.557,4.797,9.029,6.254,11.705c10.332-10.494,19.873-9.631,19.873-9.631s9.543-0.877,19.9,9.602
    c1.451-2.68,5.516-10.158,6.225-11.717C310.444,421.764,297.171,422.465,297.171,422.465z" />
    <path fill="#C52727" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="M297.165,404.046c0,0-17.482-0.683-34.387,12.198
    c0.939,1.557,6.316,9.029,8.236,11.705c13.607-10.494,26.174-9.629,26.174-9.629s12.568-0.879,26.209,9.6
    c1.906-2.68,7.262-10.156,8.195-11.717C314.646,403.344,297.165,404.046,297.165,404.046z" />
    <path fill="#D8E022" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="M297.157,385.625c0,0-21.969-0.682-43.213,12.199
    c1.18,1.557,7.938,9.029,10.352,11.705c17.098-10.494,32.895-9.63,32.895-9.63s15.793-0.878,32.936,9.601
    c2.396-2.68,9.127-10.157,10.301-11.717C319.13,384.924,297.157,385.625,297.157,385.625z" />
    <path fill="#3F52A4" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="M297.149,367.205c0,0-28.982-0.682-57.008,12.199
    c1.559,1.557,10.471,9.029,13.654,11.705c22.557-10.494,43.396-9.63,43.396-9.63s20.834-0.878,43.447,9.601
    c3.16-2.68,12.041-10.157,13.59-11.717C326.132,366.504,297.149,367.205,297.149,367.205z" />
    <path fill="#3B98D4" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="M297.142,348.785c0,0-35.719-0.682-70.26,12.198
    c1.922,1.557,12.906,9.03,16.828,11.706c27.803-10.494,53.484-9.631,53.484-9.631s25.676-0.877,53.549,9.601
    c3.893-2.679,14.838-10.157,16.746-11.716C332.86,348.083,297.142,348.785,297.142,348.785z" />
    <path fill="#B24F9E" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="M297.13,325.867c0,0-44.416-0.811-87.363,14.494
    c2.389,1.85,16.049,10.729,20.924,13.909c34.572-12.469,66.506-11.443,66.506-11.443s31.926-1.043,66.584,11.408
    c4.842-3.184,18.453-12.068,20.824-13.922C341.546,325.032,297.13,325.867,297.13,325.867z" />
    <linearGradient id="SVGID_1_" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x1="271.417" y1="434.4395" x2="323.6689" y2="434.4395">
      <stop offset="0.0545" style="stop-color:#C6E09B;stop-opacity:0.66" />
      <stop offset="0.1343" style="stop-color:#B2C98A;stop-opacity:0.5676" />
      <stop offset="0.2804" style="stop-color:#88A069;stop-opacity:0.3983" />
      <stop offset="0.475" style="stop-color:#4F6B3C;stop-opacity:0.1729" />
      <stop offset="0.6242" style="stop-color:#234821;stop-opacity:0" />
    </linearGradient>
    <path fill="url(#SVGID_1_)" d="M297.528,422.491c0,0-13.275-0.682-26.111,12.199c0.713,1.557,4.797,9.029,6.254,11.705
    c10.332-10.494,19.873-9.631,19.873-9.631s9.543-0.877,19.9,9.602c1.451-2.68,5.516-10.158,6.225-11.717
    C310.802,421.79,297.528,422.491,297.528,422.491z" />
    <linearGradient id="SVGID_2_" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x1="263.124" y1="415.9946" x2="332.5928" y2="415.9946">
      <stop offset="0.0545" style="stop-color:#C6E09B;stop-opacity:0.66" />
      <stop offset="0.1343" style="stop-color:#B2C98A;stop-opacity:0.5676" />
      <stop offset="0.2804" style="stop-color:#88A069;stop-opacity:0.3983" />
      <stop offset="0.475" style="stop-color:#4F6B3C;stop-opacity:0.1729" />
      <stop offset="0.6242" style="stop-color:#234821;stop-opacity:0" />
    </linearGradient>
    <path fill="url(#SVGID_2_)" d="M297.839,404.046c0,0-17.649-0.682-34.715,12.199c0.948,1.557,6.377,9.029,8.314,11.705
    c13.736-10.494,26.421-9.631,26.421-9.631s12.688-0.877,26.458,9.602c1.929-2.68,7.333-10.158,8.275-11.717
    C315.485,403.345,297.839,404.046,297.839,404.046z" />
    <linearGradient id="SVGID_3_" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x1="253.9443" y1="397.5737" x2="340.4268" y2="397.5737">
      <stop offset="0.0545" style="stop-color:#C6E09B;stop-opacity:0.66" />
      <stop offset="0.1343" style="stop-color:#B2C98A;stop-opacity:0.5676" />
      <stop offset="0.2804" style="stop-color:#88A069;stop-opacity:0.3983" />
      <stop offset="0.475" style="stop-color:#4F6B3C;stop-opacity:0.1729" />
      <stop offset="0.6242" style="stop-color:#234821;stop-opacity:0" />
    </linearGradient>
    <path fill="url(#SVGID_3_)" d="M297.161,385.625c0,0-21.972-0.682-43.217,12.199c1.18,1.557,7.938,9.029,10.351,11.705
    c17.101-10.494,32.892-9.631,32.892-9.631s15.796-0.877,32.938,9.602c2.401-2.68,9.129-10.158,10.303-11.717
    C319.129,384.924,297.161,385.625,297.161,385.625z" />
    <linearGradient id="SVGID_4_" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x1="240.1416" y1="378.8638" x2="355.2295" y2="378.8638">
      <stop offset="0.0545" style="stop-color:#C6E09B;stop-opacity:0.66" />
      <stop offset="0.1343" style="stop-color:#B2C98A;stop-opacity:0.5676" />
      <stop offset="0.2804" style="stop-color:#88A069;stop-opacity:0.3983" />
      <stop offset="0.475" style="stop-color:#4F6B3C;stop-opacity:0.1729" />
      <stop offset="0.6242" style="stop-color:#234821;stop-opacity:0" />
    </linearGradient>
    <path fill="url(#SVGID_4_)" d="M297.654,367.205c0,0-29.24-0.665-57.513,11.903c1.57,1.519,10.564,8.81,13.774,11.421
    c22.757-10.239,43.771-9.397,43.771-9.397s21.02-0.855,43.832,9.369c3.195-2.615,12.147-9.912,13.71-11.433
    C326.888,366.521,297.654,367.205,297.654,367.205z" />
    <linearGradient id="SVGID_5_" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x1="225.4072" y1="360.7339" x2="370.3096" y2="360.7339">
      <stop offset="0.0545" style="stop-color:#C6E09B;stop-opacity:0.66" />
      <stop offset="0.1343" style="stop-color:#B2C98A;stop-opacity:0.5676" />
      <stop offset="0.2804" style="stop-color:#88A069;stop-opacity:0.3983" />
      <stop offset="0.475" style="stop-color:#4F6B3C;stop-opacity:0.1729" />
      <stop offset="0.6242" style="stop-color:#234821;stop-opacity:0" />
    </linearGradient>
    <path fill="url(#SVGID_5_)" d="M297.818,349.075c0,0-36.814-0.665-72.411,11.903c1.978,1.519,13.301,8.81,17.343,11.421
    c28.651-10.239,55.11-9.397,55.11-9.397s26.465-0.855,55.188,9.369c4.022-2.615,15.295-9.912,17.262-11.433
    C334.626,348.391,297.818,349.075,297.818,349.075z" />
    <linearGradient id="SVGID_6_" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x1="207.0791" y1="339.6611" x2="388.25" y2="339.6611">
      <stop offset="0.0545" style="stop-color:#C6E09B;stop-opacity:0.66" />
      <stop offset="0.1343" style="stop-color:#B2C98A;stop-opacity:0.5676" />
      <stop offset="0.2804" style="stop-color:#88A069;stop-opacity:0.3983" />
      <stop offset="0.475" style="stop-color:#4F6B3C;stop-opacity:0.1729" />
      <stop offset="0.6242" style="stop-color:#234821;stop-opacity:0" />
    </linearGradient>
    <path fill="url(#SVGID_6_)" d="M297.614,325.407c0,0-46.028-0.813-90.535,14.553c2.472,1.856,16.63,10.771,21.684,13.964
    c35.823-12.519,68.904-11.489,68.904-11.489s33.089-1.046,69.001,11.455c5.029-3.198,19.124-12.119,21.582-13.979
    C343.636,324.57,297.614,325.407,297.614,325.407z" />
  </svg>
</div>
```